# how to hide js value from inspection on web

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

i am passing a secret code to the front end, from my backend. I want to store the value in my JS script, like so:

```
 <script>
        var code = '<%= code %>'
    </script>
```

then when the user types in the code, i want to run a check to make sure it matches with the code i passed through. I'm doing this so it eliminates the struggle of going to the backend and refreshing again.

However, when i right click, and inspect element, i can actually see the code in my web browser, which is a problem. Is there a better way to do this, or a way to hide it?

Comment: There's no way to hide something on the frontend if the user is determined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser works for the user not the site author.

You cannot give something to the browser and expect it to keep it a secret from the user.

Do the check server-side. Live with the extra HTTP request.

Comment: Even if it isn't in the HTML, I can still look at code from the sources tab, and even do a full memory screenshot to find values. Even if you encrypted values, you'd still need to send a request to unencrypt stuff. There's no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to have "secret" Javascript code run in the browser. The closest thing to that would be to use a minified/uglified script, but [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is also not a valid solution.