# Using Node.js and Express, how to hide Javascript code in backend?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm new with Node and Express. I would like to ask a question about how to hide Javascript code in backend. I'm using Node.js with Express. I want to avoid reading with browser inspection. I created a simple script and put the link in `index.html`, inside `head`, writing `<script src ="/javascripts/test.js"></script>`. Everything ok, works normally.

I tried to inspect the page, with `Google`, and the code is easily read by opening .

I think the reason is because i use `test.js` in the browser front-end side. How can I use it in the backend and avoid that someone can read the code? How can this be done and how? Can you explain me? Thank you

For information and completeness, the script is

```
 function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
  }
```

While on the html button I wrote:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

Comment: Putting that function in the back-end makes little sense. It displays an alert box which is only available to browsers.

Comment: @Andy Alert is just a quick example of code I've used. I don't actually need it. It was the first that came to my mind to give an example. Now I edit the question. Again for example, pretend then that I click on a button, the 2+2 code will start (contained in the test.js file) and it will print the result 4 in a textbox. How can I hide the test.js file code? Thank you

Comment: I've rolled back the question. Please don't edit questions to invalidate existing answers.

Comment: The JavaScript code that is intended to run on the client will always be visible to the inspector. That's by design, and you have to design your whole system so that whatever the client is served knows about this design choice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to hide js value from inspection on web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68167361/how-to-hide-js-value-from-inspection-on-web)

Comment: @imjared Unfortunately not, thanks anyway. But I would like to ask you a simple question: for example, if I want to write server-side a simple function with 2+2 and display 4 in a textbox when I click on the button, can I hide the code of the 2+2 function in the backend? Or is it also something that needs to be done in the browser? I upvoted and accepted your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `alert` function, defined in the [HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-alert-dev), causes the browser to display a modal message box using the browser's native UI. It's an API made available to client-side JavaScript.

While Node.js allows you to execute JavaScript on the server, it only allows you to use [JavaScript language features](https://tc39.es/ecma262) and [Node.JS API](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/) (along with third-party code subject to the same limitations).

You can't use [Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) or other browser-specific features in Node.js (excepting those which have explicit Node.js equivalents), because the server doesn't have access to them.

Making a modal message box appear in the browser is *inherently* something that has to be done in the browser, so there can't be an equivalent Node.JS API.

Comment: Alert is just a quick example of code I've used. I don't actually need it. It was the first that came to my mind to give an example. Now I edit the question. Again for example, pretend then that I click on a button, the 2+2 code will start (contained in the test.js file) and it will print the result 4 in a textbox. How can I hide the test.js file code? Thank you

Comment: @Folidex23 — You need to read an introductory tutorial on server-side programming with Node.js. Stackoverflow is designed for dealing with *specific* problems, not for explaining the very basics that tutorials already explain.

Comment: Ok, I apologize. So you confirm me that IS IT POSSIBLE to hide the code in server side? Can you also confirm that IT IS POSSIBILE to hide the code of the example I wrote to you in the comment with 2+2? Thank you

Comment: Server-side code isn't exposed to the client. URLs to access server side code are.

Comment: URLs to access server side code are...? Ok, the server side code is not exposed to the client. But for example purposes, if I want to write in server side a simple function with 2+2 and display 4 in a textbox when I click the button, can I hide the code of the 2+2 function? Or is this also something that needs to be done in the browser? I upvoted and accepted your answer

Comment: @Folidex23 you would have to have a way for the client and server code to communicate (ie an Express API). The client would send a request to the server, the server would run the code, and return the result. You would then need some further code in the client to receive the result sent from the server, and then add it to the text box.